# Adding image from resources to VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, resources, pdfsharp

I want to add an image from resources to a pdf file.
Tools used are - PDFSharp, MS Visual Studio Express 2012
Language - VB.Net

Currently I am trying to load an image from a drive location as shown below.

```
Logo = XImage.FromFile("D:\FullPDF.jpg")
```

But the image should be loaded from the available resources in the application itself.
Please give me a way to accomplish this.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Didnt you answer your own question? Add the image to Resources and load from there

Comment: I want to know the command which loads the image from the resource.